# Unable to load a csv file into a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Even when the command prompt is inside the *lib/tasks* directory, it simply responds **"No such file or directory"** when given the command **rake populate**

**Direcory Structure**

*lib/tasks*

seed.rake

type.csv

**Files**

*seed.rake* :

```
task :populate do
    require 'csv'
    CSV.foreach('type.csv', headers: true) do |row|
        puts line
    end
end
```

*type.csv* :

```
"26","Accessories"
"24","Activ8"
"17","Bandages"
"29","Biohazard"
"1","BS8599-1 First Aid Kits"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind - wrong path. There is some missunderstanding between you and the task about  what is the start point of your path. So try outputing the current_path in the rake task to see where is it loading and then just navigate from there. 
My best guess would be that the rake task sets the path to the rails root path, but I might be wrong there.

Comment: Yes, spot on about the rake task setting the path to the root path. A huge gotcha. So used to referencing files (js/css ect) relatively!